# Issue with image picker allows editing

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I have this method for when the user opens their camera roll. I have the allows editing set to YES but when on the editing screen the square crop box only appears on iphone and not iPad. What am I missing?

```
- (void)useCameraRoll 
{
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
        if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
        {
            [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
        else
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                [self setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
                [self.navigationController presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
            });
        }

    }
}
```

And delegate method

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSString *mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage])
    {
        theCustomImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
        [self roundedCorners];
        [self placeImage:theCustomImage];
        customImage = true;
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(theCustomImage, self, @selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
    }
}
```

Comment: try removing the form sheet presentation. just a hunch, I can't verify if it will work.

Comment: didn'nt help. thanks though for the look